How do I display images stored in bytes on my nextjs frontend?
I'm trying to display images loaded from byte data in my nextjs app. I fetch the images from a Prisma postgres database where the images are stored as Bytea
When I console log the response, the image Object looks something like
{1: 34, 2: 90, 3: 150, 4: 11, etc 
I have no idea what type of data that is and I can't expand the object because it's like 6MB of binary and crashes my browser
This is my page:
https://codefile.io/f/YRqujY3Dcc
"use client"

import { Box, Button, Divider, List, ListItem, ListItemText, Paper } from "@mui/material"
import Image from "next/image"
import { Dispatch, useEffect, useState } from "react"

type Offer = {
    id: number,
    oferta: string,
    banca: string,
    descriere: string,
    imagine: any
}

function OffersView() {
    const [offers, setOffers] = useState<Offer[]>(
        [
            {
                id: 1,
                oferta: "n/a",
                banca: "n/a",
                descriere: "n/a",
                imagine: null
            }
        ]
    );

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchOffers(setOffers);  
    },[])

    return (
        <Box width={400}
            height="100vh"
            sx={{backgroundColor: "teal"}}
        >

            <List>
                {
                    offers.map(offer => 

                        <ListItem key={offer.id}>
                            <Paper>
                                <ListItemText
                                    primary={offer.banca}
                                />

                                <Divider />

                                <ListItemText
                                    primary={offer.oferta}
                                />

                                <Divider />

                                <ListItemText
                                    primary={offer.descriere}
                                />    

                                {
                                    offer.imagine && 
                                      <Image 
                                          width={200}
                                          height={200}
                                          src={`data:image/jpeg;base64, ${processImageData(offer.imagine, setImgUrl)}`}
                                          src={processImageData(offer.imagine)}
                                          alt=""
                                      />  
                                }
                                                        
                            </Paper>
                                                
                        </ListItem>
                    )
                }
            </List>
        </Box> 
    )
}

const fetchOffers = async(setOffers: Dispatch<Offer[]>) => {
    try{
        const response = await fetch("api/offer/visualize")

        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error(`Response status: ${response.status}`);
        }
        const json = await response.json();
        setOffers(json)

        processImageData(json[0].imagine)
    } catch(error){
        console.error(error)
    }
}

const processImageData = (imageData: any) => {
    /* this is what I've tried so far... */
  
    //imageData.blob = new Uint8Array(imageData.blob) as Buffer;
    //return imageData

    /* and... */
  
    // const arrayBufferView = new Uint8Array( imageData );
    // const blob = new Blob( [ arrayBufferView ], { type: "image/png" } );
    // const urlCreator = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
    // const imageUrl = urlCreator.createObjectURL( blob );
    // return imageUrl;

    /* and ... */
  
    // const imageBlob = imageData.blob();
    // const reader = new FileReader();
    // reader.readAsDataURL(imageBlob);
    // reader.onloadend = () => {
    //   const base64data = reader.result;
    //   setImgUrl(base64data);
    // };


    return btoa(String.fromCharCode(...new Uint8Array(imageData)))

}

export default OffersView

This is my POST api route where I covert the file to a buffer of ... something:
https://codefile.io/f/IgtgwhFlfm
export const POST = async(request: NextRequest, response: NextResponse) => {
  
    const data = await request.formData();
    const file: File | null = data.get("image") as unknown as File;

    if(!file){
        return NextResponse.json({success: false})
    }

    const bytes = await file.arrayBuffer();
    const buffer = Buffer.from(bytes);

    const result = await prisma.oferta.create({
        data: {
            oferta: data.get("offer") as string,
            banca: data.get("bank") as string,
            descriere: data.get("description") as string,
            imagine: buffer
        }
    })

    if (!result) {
        throw new Error("no form...");
    }else{
        NextResponse.json({success: true})
    }

    return NextResponse.json(result)
}

And this is my prisma schema:
    model Oferta{
      id Int @id @default(autoincrement())
      oferta String
      banca String
      descriere String
      imagine Bytes @db.ByteA

    }


Did you try to convert it using a blob?

const data = {1: 34, 2: 90, ...};
const byteArray = new Uint8Array(data);
const blob = new Blob([byteArray], { type: "image/png" });
const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

Yes, the image came out blank like the other commented attempts...

first transform your object to an array like this
//Object.entries({1: 34, 2: 90, 3: 150}).map(([,v])=>v)
const array = Object.entries(data).map(([,v])=>v)
const byteArray = new Uint8Array(data);
const blob = new Blob([byteArray], { type: "image/png" });
const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

after that make it a uint8 array and try again.
